# Why do I keep receiving error message when changing the URL in address bar of SPA - Azure AD

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, single-page-application

The following message is what I get when changing the URL manually in the address bar of a web browser:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
> changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I have no clue what's wrong?...

Comment: Your server needs to rewrite all requests for non-existing paths to index.html - this way, Angular can handle the routes.

Comment: Where have you deployed your SPA? As @MikeOne said, this is most likely an issue that the server is trying to route the request when in fact the client-side needs to handle the route.

Comment: Do you have an example or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Mike, @Juunas for the comment.

Based on the error, it shows Client-Side should route the request, instead Server is routing the request.

Basically when you click a link, some Javascript runs that manipulates the URL in the address bar, without causing a page refresh, which in turn causes React Router to perform a page transition on the client-side.

Bypassing the problem altogether: Hash History

With Hash History instead of Browser History, your URL for the about page would look something like this: http://example.com/#/about The part after the hash (#) symbol is not sent to the server. So the server only sees http://example.com/ and sends the index page as expected. React-Router will pick up the #/about part and show the correct page.

Please refer the below So thread for document on Server side vs Client side.

[React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)